# How do you establish a connection to a server in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to create an application which will connect to a file server and download a few video files. The server is a shared hosting Linux server.

I don't want code or anything like that, I just want to know whether this is possible and if so, what should I be researching. Should I be using java sockets? Or can Java sockets only connect to java based servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Should I be using java sockets?*

Depends on the type of server you connect to. You can use an existing library which will abstract the interaction with the server for you (recommended) or implement the required protocol yourself (not recommended).

*Can Java sockets only connect to java based servers?*

Sockets in Java are just an interface to the native socket API of the OS you are on. Every program that connects to a server over the network has to use them, regardless of whether it is a C/C++/Python/Java/... application. So, to answer your question; no, "Java sockets" can connect to *any* server.

Read more about sockets in [this Wikipedia article about sockets in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket) or [this one about Berkeley sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) (the socket API implemented by most operating systems).

Comment: An example library to use is [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) which has stuff like an FTP client build in.